# Seed Database with Data for Each User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out the best way to populate the database for each user. My end target is to have each `user` who `has_many` `goals` have a list of prepopulated `goals` when the user is created. The issue I see with seeding is that this will only create ONE set of goals for every user to "share" and not an individual set of goals for each user with the same initial data.

This is my current layout:

**weekly_goals table**

```
user_id
title
status
```

**User.rb**

```
has_many :weekly_goals
```

**WeeklyGoal.rb**

```
belongs_to :user

#List of all goals hardcoded in
```

Am I going about this with the wrong thought process? Is there a better way to do what I'm asking? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
goals = ['goal1', 'goal2', 'goal3', 'gaol4', 'goal5', 'goal6', 'goal7' ]

['user1', 'user2', 'user3'].each do |usr|
   user = User.create(name: usr)
   7.times do 
     user.weekly_goals.create(name: goals.sample)
   end
end
```

Here i took 3 users and i create 7 goals for each user and while creating the weekly goal i took random goal so every user have different set of goals.

Another solution is you can user [faker gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) to populate dumm

Comment: This is the exact process I was going to take, but it seems like it was kind of sloppy to do it for each 1000+ users

Comment: so from where do you want to import user and goals ie. from csv or from database?

Comment: csv unless there is a way to make a template table in the database and then just copy that for each user.

Comment: you can write a import utility where you can read data from csv and insert in database.

Comment: I haven't done anything like that. I was just going to create a yml file and then a method to pull data from that and populate the tables.

Comment: that's also cool ,  what's the problem in doing that?. You can read the goals from that file and assign them randomly to users.

Comment: No problem, it just seemed inefficient I guess, I could be overthinking it. I will go ahead with this solution, thank you for your help :)